# CSS - Is, or was, "initial" a valid argument for the transform translate (X, Y, or Z) function?

Tags: css, translate

I was scanning the CSS for one of our company's websites. I came across

```
transform: translateX(initial);
```

I have never seen this and thought according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) MDN link and the transform doc [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property) that only length and percentage values are allowed as arguments. Trying `initial` on a CSS/HTML snippet I quickly cooked up seems that it breaks the transform.

Was "initial" ever (or maybe even, is it still) an acceptable argument for translateX(), translateY(), or translateZ()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your assessment is correct. But, according to [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp):

> The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.
>
> The initial keyword **can be used for any CSS property**, and on any HTML element.

So, even though

```css
transform: translateX(initial);
```

is not valid,

```css
transform: initial;
```

is completely fine, and is probably what the author intended (citation needed).